# Understanding MySQL select order by Rand: why is unrelated KEY used in some case?

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, sql-order-by

Here's exactly what I did

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

### Case 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo2` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column3` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `composite` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
# BASH: for i in `seq 1 10000`; do mysql -uroot -p"password" -e "replace into foo_db.Foo2 (\`id\`,\`column1\`,\`column2\`,\`column3\`) values ($((i * 2)), ${i}, $((i + 1)), NOW());" >/dev/null 2>&1; done
```

and the following explain with result

```
explain select * from foo_db.Foo2 order by RAND() limit 5;
```

[image]

```
select count(*) from foo_db.Foo2;
# result : 10000
```

### Case 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo3` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column3` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `composite` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
# BASH: for i in `seq 1 10000`; do mysql -uroot -p"password" -e "replace into foo_db.Foo3 (\`id\`,\`column1\`,\`column2\`,\`column3\`) values ($((i * 2)), ${i}, $((i + 1)), NOW());" >/dev/null 2>&1; done
```

```
explain select * from foo_db.Foo3 order by RAND() limit 5;
```

[image]

```
explain select `id` from foo_db.Foo3 order by RAND() limit 5;
```

[image]

```
select count(*) from foo_db.Foo3;
# result : 10000
```

### Points that I don't understand

1. Why the number of rows shown in explain does not match the actual select count(*)?
2. In Case 1, why the unrelated `composite` key is used in `order by RAND()` while `possible_keys` is null?
3. In Case 2, why the behavior is different from Case 1 with `select *` but the behavior becomes the same as Case 1 if I do `select id` instead?
4. In Case 2, why is the primary key `id` not used in the `select id` result?

Partial helps would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me list a bunch of things.  These will handle some of your questions.

- The Optimizer can read the data's BTree or a secondary index's BTree.  In the latter case, the INDEX is called "covering" and indicated in EXPLAIN via "Using index".
- ENGINE=InnoDB includes all the PK columns in each secondary index.
- Case 1's secondary index contains all the columns that are needed for `SELECT *`.
- Therefore, cases 1 and 2b can use a covering index.
- The Optimizer, if given a choice of which BTree to use, usually picks the smaller one.  *Perhaps* the secondary index for case 1 happened to be smaller.
- The PRIMARY KEY is "clustered" with the data.

Now for your specific questions.

1. With InnoDB, the exact number of rows is not kept; instead it is estimated at run time.  Explain's "Rows" column is sometimes off by a factor of 2 either way.  (Sometimes even farther off.)
2. Why "NULL"?  (See above, plus...)  One of those mysteries of life.  I find it low on the list of things to figure out.
3. and
4. `SELECT *` needs all the columns, but there are now some columns that are not in the secondary index.`SELECT id` -- as mentioned above about the "smallest".

Somewhat related:  See [*Random*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) for the fastest algorithms for fetching a random *subset* of a table.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I roughly understood the point now, but there is a small detail for question 4 that I am still not really clear. Basically the secondary index "composite" is the "smallest" because the "primary key id index" BTree is somehow bigger than the "composite" index, is my understanding correct? If so, why is it bigger though ?

Comment: @cr001 - The PRIMARY KEY is not a separate BTree -- it is included with the data.  So, _usually_ the PK (+data) is a bigger BTree than any secondary key.  Apparently it is the other way in this case.  `SHOW TABLE STATUS` _may_ give a clue.

Comment: It is not easy to discover the actual size of each index.  Possibly one BTree is more fragmented than the other, thereby occupying more blocks even though it contains no more data.  A block is 16KB and contains perhaps 100 data or index rows.